# Stored procedures and classes

Tags: .net, stored-procedures

I struggle to understand when to offset business logic to stored procedures and when to include in in .NET.  I am developing a system that deletes information from other systems.  Please see the code below:

```
Public Interface Deleteable
    Sub Delete()

End Interface

Public Class Database1
    Implements Deleteable

    Public Sub Delete() Implements Deleteable.Delete
        'Logic to implement deletion from system 1 i.e. 1) can I delete? and 2) If I can delete then execute delete.

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Database2
    Implements Deleteable

    Public Sub Delete() Implements Deleteable.Delete
        'Logic to implement deletion from system 1 i.e. 1) can I delete? and 2) If I can delete then execute delete.

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Database3
    Implements Deleteable

    Public Sub Delete() Implements Deleteable.Delete
        'Logic to implement deletion from system 1 i.e. 1) can I delete? and 2) If I can delete then execute delete.

    End Sub
End Class
```

Instead of going this I could create stored procedures in each of the databases.  Is there criteria people use to decide when to use stored procedures?

Comment: You can use an abstract class to put the common implementation for `Delete` in a single location (instead of having to implement `Delete` for every single `IDeleteable`). That said, whether you want to use a stored procedure or include the logic in your data access layer does not matter to the rest of the application, so it isn't a major concern.

Comment: In my opinion, your database should contain CRUD logic and large set operations like aggregations, searches, data merges etc. Your code should contain entity relationships, workflows, any mathematical heavy lifting (you don't want to do matrix algebra in a stored proc).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, anything related to the database that *can* be run at the DB end, should be run there.

There are some special cases were sometimes you need some extra logic but for the most part if its a common piece of DB logic and is executed frequently then it would be more efficient as a stored procedure.

Comment: "then it would be more efficient as a stored procedure" - that gets a little hazy; modern RDBMS use the same query-plan cache for both sproc  and raw text, the main difference just being the bandwidth of the command itself - which usually won't be noticed